# Double click using Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

Seems to not be a supported feature unless you use firewatir?

I've browsed around for it, can't seem to find it anywhere, I came across double_click but that returned an undefined method error in console.

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `double_click` method for elements.

Try:

```
browser.element.double_click
```

Note that `element` does not have to be an element type. It can be a subclass, like a link, span, etc.

Related rdocs: [Watir-Classic](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-classic/Watir/Element#double_click-instance_method) and [Watir-Webdriver](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#double_click-instance_method)

Answer (score 4):

You could also try the fire_event("ondblclick") method

```
browser.link(:id,”object_to_doubleclick”).fire_event(”ondblclick”)
```

fire_event method supports many different events including

- onmousemove
- onmouseover
- onmousedown
- onmouseup
- onclick
- onmouseout and many more...

Comment: This is the answer that works if you are using PhantomJS. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with FoxMulder900